# ANTLR grammar for reStructuredText (rule priorities)

Tags: antlr, antlr3, restructuredtext

### First question stream

Hello everyone,

This could be a follow-up on this question: [Antlr rule priorities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899538/antlr-rule-priorities)

I'm trying to write an ANTLR grammar for the [reStructuredText markup language](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html).

The main problem I'm facing is : **"How to match any sequence of characters (regular text) without masking other grammar rules?"**

Let's take an example with a paragraph with inline markup:

```
In `Figure 17-6`_, we have positioned ``before_ptr`` so that it points to the element 
*before* the insert point. The variable ``after_ptr`` points to the element *after* the 
insert. In other words, we are going to put our new element **in between** ``before_ptr`` 
and ``after_ptr``.
```

I thought that writing rules for inline markup text would be easy. So I wrote a simple grammar:

```
grammar Rst;

options {
    output=AST;
    language=Java;
    backtrack=true;
    //memoize=true;
}

@members {
boolean inInlineMarkup = false;
}

// PARSER

text
    : inline_markup (WS? inline_markup)* WS? EOF
    ;


inline_markup
@after {
inInlineMarkup = false;
}
    : {!inInlineMarkup}? (emphasis|strong|litteral|link)
    ;

emphasis
@init {
inInlineMarkup = true;
}
    : '*' (~'*')+ '*' {System.out.println("emphasis: " + $text);}
    ;

strong
@init {
inInlineMarkup = true;
}
    : '**' (~'*')+ '**' {System.out.println("bold: " + $text);}
    ;

litteral
@init {
inInlineMarkup = true;
}
    : '``' (~'`')+ '``' {System.out.println("litteral: " + $text);}
    ;

link
@init {
inInlineMarkup = true;
}
    : inline_internal_target
    | footnote_reference
    | hyperlink_reference
    ;

inline_internal_target
    : '_`' (~'`')+ '`' {System.out.println("inline_internal_target: " + $text);}
    ;

footnote_reference
    : '[' (~']')+ ']_' {System.out.println("footnote_reference: " + $text);}
    ;


hyperlink_reference
    : ~(' '|'\t'|'\u000C'|'_')+ '_' {System.out.println("hyperlink_reference: " + $text);}
    |   '`' (~'`')+ '`_' {System.out.println("hyperlink_reference (long): " + $text);}
    ;

// LEXER

WS  
  : (' '|'\t'|'\u000C')+
  ; 

NEWLINE
  : '\r'? '\n'
  ;
```

This simple grammar doesn't work. And I didn't even try to match **regular** text...

**My questions:**

- Could someone point to my errors and maybe give me a hint on how to match **regular** text?
- Is there a way to set priority on the grammar rules? Maybe this could be a lead.

Thanks in advance for your help :-)

Robin

---

### Second question stream

Thank you very much for your help! I would have had a hard time figuring my errors... I'm not writing that grammar (only) to learn ANTLR, I'm trying to code an IDE plugin for eclipse. And for that, I need a grammar ;)

I managed to go further in the grammar and wrote a `text` rule:

```
grammar Rst;

options {
    output=AST;
    language=Java;
}



@members {
boolean inInlineMarkup = false;
}

//////////////////
// PARSER RULES //
//////////////////

file
  : line* EOF
  ;


line
  : text* NEWLINE
  ;

text
    : inline_markup
    | normal_text
    ;

inline_markup
@after {
inInlineMarkup = false;
}
    : {!inInlineMarkup}? {inInlineMarkup = true;} 
  (
  | STRONG
  | EMPHASIS
  | LITTERAL
  | INTERPRETED_TEXT
  | SUBSTITUTION_REFERENCE
  | link
  )
    ;


link
    : INLINE_INTERNAL_TARGET
    | FOOTNOTE_REFERENCE
    | HYPERLINK_REFERENCE
    ;

normal_text
  : {!inInlineMarkup}? 
   ~(EMPHASIS
      |SUBSTITUTION_REFERENCE
      |STRONG
      |LITTERAL
      |INTERPRETED_TEXT
      |INLINE_INTERNAL_TARGET
      |FOOTNOTE_REFERENCE
      |HYPERLINK_REFERENCE
      |NEWLINE
      )
  ;
//////////////////
// LEXER TOKENS //
//////////////////

EMPHASIS
    : STAR ANY_BUT_STAR+ STAR {System.out.println("EMPHASIS: " + $text);}
    ;

SUBSTITUTION_REFERENCE
  : PIPE ANY_BUT_PIPE+ PIPE  {System.out.println("SUBST_REF: " + $text);}
  ;

STRONG
    : STAR STAR ANY_BUT_STAR+ STAR STAR {System.out.println("STRONG: " + $text);}
    ;

LITTERAL
    : BACKTICK BACKTICK ANY_BUT_BACKTICK+ BACKTICK BACKTICK {System.out.println("LITTERAL: " + $text);}
    ;
INTERPRETED_TEXT
  : BACKTICK ANY_BUT_BACKTICK+ BACKTICK {System.out.println("LITTERAL: " + $text);}
  ;

INLINE_INTERNAL_TARGET
    : UNDERSCORE BACKTICK ANY_BUT_BACKTICK+ BACKTICK {System.out.println("INLINE_INTERNAL_TARGET: " + $text);}
    ;

FOOTNOTE_REFERENCE
    : L_BRACKET ANY_BUT_BRACKET+ R_BRACKET UNDERSCORE {System.out.println("FOOTNOTE_REFERENCE: " + $text);}
    ;


HYPERLINK_REFERENCE
  : BACKTICK ANY_BUT_BACKTICK+ BACKTICK UNDERSCORE {System.out.println("HYPERLINK_REFERENCE (long): " + $text);}
  | ANY_BUT_ENDLINK+ UNDERSCORE {System.out.println("HYPERLINK_REFERENCE (short): " + $text);}
  ;

WS  
  : (' '|'\t')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;}
  ; 

NEWLINE
  : '\r'? '\n' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
  ;


///////////////
// FRAGMENTS //
///////////////

fragment ANY_BUT_PIPE
  : ESC PIPE
  | ~(PIPE|'\n'|'\r')
  ;
fragment ANY_BUT_BRACKET
  : ESC R_BRACKET
  | ~(R_BRACKET|'\n'|'\r')
  ;
fragment ANY_BUT_STAR
  : ESC STAR
  | ~(STAR|'\n'|'\r')
  ;
fragment ANY_BUT_BACKTICK
  : ESC BACKTICK
  | ~(BACKTICK|'\n'|'\r')
  ;
fragment ANY_BUT_ENDLINK
  : ~(UNDERSCORE|' '|'\t'|'\n'|'\r')
  ;



fragment ESC
  : '\\'
  ;
fragment STAR
  : '*'
  ;
fragment BACKTICK
  : '`'
  ;
fragment PIPE
  : '|'
  ;
fragment L_BRACKET
  : '['
  ;
fragment R_BRACKET
  : ']'
  ;
fragment UNDERSCORE
  : '_'
  ;
```

The grammar is working fine for inline_markup but normal_text is not matched.

Here is my test class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;

import org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRStringStream;
import org.antlr.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.runtime.RecognitionException;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.Tree;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RecognitionException, IOException {

        InputStream is = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("test.rst");
        Reader r = new InputStreamReader(is);
        StringBuilder source = new StringBuilder();
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        int readLenght = 0;
        while ((readLenght = r.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            if (readLenght < buffer.length) {
                source.append(buffer, 0, readLenght);
            } else {
                source.append(buffer);
            }
        }
        r.close();
        System.out.println(source.toString());

        ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream(source.toString());
        RstLexer lexer = new RstLexer(in);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        RstParser parser = new RstParser(tokens);
        RstParser.file_return out = parser.file();
        System.out.println(((Tree)out.getTree()).toStringTree());
    }
}
```

And the input file I use:

```
In `Figure 17-6`_, we have positioned ``before_ptr`` so that it points to the element 
*before* the insert point. The variable ``after_ptr`` points to the |element| *after* the 
insert. In other words, `we are going`_ to put_ our new element **in between** ``before_ptr`` 
and ``after_ptr``.
```

And I get this output:

```
HYPERLINK_REFERENCE (short): 7-6`_
line 1:2 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 1:10 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 1:18 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 1:21 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 1:26 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 1:37 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
LITTERAL: `before_ptr`
line 1:86 no viable alternative at character '\r'
line 1:55 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 1:60 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 1:63 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 1:70 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 1:73 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 1:77 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 1:85 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
EMPHASIS: *before*
line 2:12 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 2:19 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 2:26 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
LITTERAL: `after_ptr`
line 2:30 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 2:39 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 2:90 no viable alternative at character '\r'
line 2:60 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 2:63 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 2:67 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 2:77 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 2:85 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 2:89 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 3:7 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 3:10 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 3:16 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 3:23 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 3:27 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 3:31 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 3:42 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 3:51 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 3:55 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 3:63 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 3:94 mismatched character '\r' expecting '*'
line 4:3 mismatched character ' ' expecting '_'
line 4:18 no viable alternative at character '\r'
line 4:18 mismatched character '\r' expecting '_'
HYPERLINK_REFERENCE (short): oing`_
HYPERLINK_REFERENCE (short): ut_
EMPHASIS: *in between*
LITTERAL: `after_ptr`
BR.recoverFromMismatchedToken
line 0:-1 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting NEWLINE
null
```

Can you point to my error(s)? (the parser works for inline markup without errors when I add the filter=true; option to the grammar)

Robin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a quick demo how you *could* parse this reStructeredText. Note that it just handles a minor set of all available markup-syntax, and by adding more to it, you **will** affect the existing parser/lexer rules: so there is much, *much* more work to be done!

### Demo

```
grammar RST;

options {
  output=AST;
  backtrack=true;
  memoize=true;
}

tokens {
  ROOT;
  PARAGRAPH;
  INDENTATION;
  LINE;
  WORD;
  BOLD;
  ITALIC;
  INTERPRETED_TEXT;
  INLINE_LITERAL;
  REFERENCE;
}

parse
  :  paragraph+ EOF -> ^(ROOT paragraph+)
  ;

paragraph
  :  line+ -> ^(PARAGRAPH line+)
  |  Space* LineBreak -> /* omit line-breaks between paragraphs from AST */
  ;

line
  :  indentation text+ LineBreak -> ^(LINE text+)
  ;

indentation
  :  Space* -> ^(INDENTATION Space*)
  ;

text
  :  styledText
  |  interpretedText
  |  inlineLiteral
  |  reference
  |  Space
  |  Star
  |  EscapeSequence
  |  Any
  ;

styledText
  :  bold
  |  italic
  ;

bold
  :  Star Star boldAtom+ Star Star -> ^(BOLD boldAtom+)
  ;  

italic
  :  Star italicAtom+ Star -> ^(ITALIC italicAtom+)
  ;

boldAtom
  :  ~(Star | LineBreak)
  |  italic
  ;

italicAtom
  :  ~(Star | LineBreak)
  |  bold
  ;

interpretedText
  :  BackTick interpretedTextAtoms BackTick -> ^(INTERPRETED_TEXT interpretedTextAtoms)
  ;

interpretedTextAtoms
  :  ~BackTick+
  ;

inlineLiteral
  :  BackTick BackTick inlineLiteralAtoms BackTick BackTick -> ^(INLINE_LITERAL inlineLiteralAtoms)
  ;

inlineLiteralAtoms
  :  inlineLiteralAtom+
  ;

inlineLiteralAtom
  :  ~BackTick
  |  BackTick ~BackTick
  ;

reference
  :  Any+ UnderScore -> ^(REFERENCE Any+)
  ;

UnderScore
  :  '_'
  ;

BackTick
  :  '`'
  ;

Star
  :  '*'
  ;

Space
  :  ' ' 
  |  '\t'
  ;

EscapeSequence
  :  '\\' ('\\' | '*')
  ;

LineBreak
  :  '\r'? '\n'
  |  '\r'
  ;

Any
  :  .
  ;
```

When you generate a parser and lexer from the above, and let it parse the following input file:

```
***x*** **yyy** *zz* *
a b c

P2 ``*a*`b`` `q`
Python_
```

*(note the trailing line break!)*

the parser will produce the following AST:

[image]

### EDIT

The graph can be created by running this class:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String source =
        "***x*** **yyy** *zz* *\n" +
        "a b c\n" +
        "\n" +
        "P2 ``*a*`b`` `q`\n" +
        "Python_\n";
    RSTLexer lexer = new RSTLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(source));
    RSTParser parser = new RSTParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)parser.parse().getTree();
    DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
    StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(tree);
    System.out.println(st);
  }
}
```

or if your source comes from a file, do:

```java
RSTLexer lexer = new RSTLexer(new ANTLRFileStream("test.rst"));
```

or

```java
RSTLexer lexer = new RSTLexer(new ANTLRFileStream("test.rst", "???"));
```

where `"???"` is the encoding of your file.

The class above will print the AST as a DOT file to the console. You can use a DOT viewer to display the AST. In this case, I posted an image created by [kgraphviewer](http://www.kde.org/applications/graphics/kgraphviewer/). But there are [many more viewers around](http://www.graphviz.org/Resources.php). A nice online one is [this one](http://graphviz-dev.appspot.com/), which appears to be using [kgraphviewer](http://www.kde.org/applications/graphics/kgraphviewer/) under "the hood". Good luck!

Comment: Hello Bart :-) Thanks for the help! Quick question: How do you generate the AST? ANTLRWorks fails because of the "backtrack=true;" option.

Comment: @Robin, even without the `backtrack=true`, ANTLRWorks would not have displayed the AST produced by the parser rules. ANTLRWorks generates the parse tree (if you're not sure what the difference is between the two, see [this previous Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729961/any-differences-between-terms-parse-trees-and-derivation-trees)). See the **EDIT** for the AST image creation. And you're welcome.

Comment: Just a notice for future readers. I intend to use this grammar as the starting point of a serious reStructuredText grammar, and of course will update it for ANTLR v4, https://github.com/lextm/restructuredtext-antlr

Answer (score 4):

> ***Robin wrote:***
>
> I thought that writing rules for inline markup text would be easy

I must admit that I am not familiar with this markup language, but it seems to resemble BB-Code or Wiki markup which are not easily translated into a (ANTLR) grammar! These languages don't let themselves be easily tokenized since it depends on where these tokens occur. White spaces sometimes have a special meaning (with definition lists). So no, it's not at all easy, IMO. So if this is just an exercise for you to get acquainted to ANTLR (or parser generators in general), I **highly** recommend choosing something else to parse.

> ***Robin wrote:***
>
> Could someone point to my errors and maybe give me a hint on how to match regular text?

You must first realize that ANTLR creates a lexer (tokenizer) and parser. Lexer rules start with a upper case letter and parser rules start with a lower case. A parser can only operate on tokens (the objects that are made by lexer rules). To keep things orderly, you *should* not use token-literals inside parser rules (see rule `q` in the grammar below). Also, the `~` (negation) meta char has a different meaning depending on where it's used (in a parser- or lexer rule).

Take the following grammar:

```
p : T;
q : ~'z';

T : ~'x';
U : 'y';
```

ANTLR will first "move" the `'z'` literal to a lexer rule like this:

```
p : T;
q : ~RANDOM_NAME;

T : ~'x';
U : 'y';
RANDOM_NAME : 'z';
```

(the name `RANDOM_NAME` is not used, but that doesn't matter). Now, the parser rule `q` does **not** match any character other than `'z'`! A negation inside a parser rule negates a token (or lexer rule). So `~RANDOM_NAME` will match either lexer rule `T` or lexer rule `U`.

Inside lexer rules, `~` negates (single!) characters. So the lexer rule `T` will match any character in the range `\u0000`..`\uFFFF` except `'x'`. Note that the following: `~'ab'` is invalid inside a lexer rule: you can only negate single character sets.

So, all these `~'???'` inside your parser rules are wrong (wrong as in: they don't behave as you expect them to).

> ***Robin wrote:***
>
> Is there a way to set priority on the grammar rules? Maybe this could be a lead.

Yes, the order is top to bottom in both lexer- and parser rules (where the top has the highest priority). Let's say `parse` is the entry point of your grammar:

```
parse
  :  p
  |  q
  ;
```

then `p` will first be tried, and if that fails, `q` is tried to match.

As for lexer rules, the rules that are keywords for example are matched before a rule that could possible match said keywords:

```
// first keywords:
WHILE : 'while';
IF    : 'if'
ELSE  : 'else';

// and only then, the identifier rule: 
ID    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '0'..'9')*;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I would have had a hard time figuring my errors... I'm not writing that grammar (only) to learn ANTLR, I'm trying to code an IDE plugin for eclipse. And for that, I need a grammar ;) PS: I edited my initial question, sorry about the extra post.